# react-async-poll with a connected component

Tags: reactjs, polling

Looking at the [docs for react-async-poll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-async-poll) I'm following the Usage example to integrate `asyncPoll` into my component, but I'm getting a `Uncaught TypeError: dispatch is not a function` complaint from within my `onPollinterval` function

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import asyncPoll from 'react-async-poll';
import { fetchCaCities, } from '../actions';
import MyMap from './my-map';

class CaliforniaMap extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchCaCities();
  } 

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>California Map</h1>
        <MyMap center={[37.5, -120]} zoom={6} layers={[this.props.caCities]} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const onPollInterval = (props, dispatch) => {
  console.log(dispatch); // undefined
  return dispatch(fetchCaCities());
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  caCities: state.map.california.caCities,
});

export default asyncPoll(60 * 1000, onPollInterval)(connect(
  mapStateToProps, { fetchCaCities }
)(CaliforniaMap)
```

Maybe `react-async-poll` doesn't work for connected components?

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs:

> The dispatch parameter is only passed to [onInterval] if it is
>   available in props, otherwise it will be undefined.

The example they give is confusing because it does not define `dispatch` anywhere, but they show `onPollInterval` using it.